# Help with displaying screen on monitor

Tags: laptop

Dog knocked my laptop off the table and smashed the screen. I was able to display on an external monitor once. I unplugged everything to move it and when I set it all back up i coudlnt get it to display on the monitor. Are there any shortcuts on the keyboard to get in, the laptops an HP 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a combination of the function key (`Fn` on the keyboard) and one of the function buttons F1 - F12.

On mine it's Fn+F2. You can google the info for you laptop model.